# Setting max and min limit on input field?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am having this issue where i have a vuetify text-field and i am trying to set a max and min limit on it. Now setting min=0 and max=10 works but seems like you could still paste values more than 10.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/orKMyJ?editors=1111)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-text-field
         type="number"
         min=0
         max=10
         onkeyup="if(this.value > 10) this.value = 10;">    
        </v-text-field>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }
 })
```

Using the onkeyup works but you can still paste values greater than 10 and if you click outside, the value greater than 10 shows up.

Comment: use oninput instead

Comment: @epascarello thanks. problem solved. if you want to add this as an answer, i'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use oninput and I would not hardcode the values

```
oninput="if(Number(this.value) > Number(this.max)) this.value = this.max;"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put attributes on input element manually (although this solution is not clear, in fact i would call it hack, but it's easy to do)

Put $ref on you field

```
<v-text-field ref="myfield" ... >
```

and then you can modify it as mounted

```
mounted () {
  const inputElement = this.$refs.myfield.$el.querySelector('input')
  inputElement.min = 0
  inputElement.max = 10
}
```

You can also modify any other attribute like `step`, or `maxLength` (for text type). Refer input element API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: If you wanna use without the querySelector, you can access the input element like this: `this.$refs.myfield.$refs.input`, v-text-fields also have a $refs with html componentes used

Answer (score 1):

You can use data rules for this as well.

Eg:
Inside data

```
data(){
organization: "",
      organizationRules: [
        (v) => !!v || "Organization is required",
        (v) =>
          (v && v.length <= 50) ||
          "Organization must be less than 50 characters",
      ],
}
```

Inside template

```
<template>
<v-text-field
          v-model="organization"
          :counter="50"
          :rules="organizationRules"
          label="Organization"
          required
        ></v-text-field>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have maximum 2 digits before and after the decimals then here's the implementation for that

template

```html
<v-text-field v-model="input" v-on:keyup="handleInput" type="number" oninput="if(Number(this.value) > Number(this.max)) this.value = this.max;" max="99" ></v-text-field>
```

script

```js
 handleInput(e) {
      let stringValue = e.target.value.toString();

      let regex = /^\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
      if (!stringValue.match(regex) && this.budget !== "") {
        this.budget = this.previousPrice;
      }
      this.previousPrice = this.budget;
    },
```

you can customize the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/kiWOMz/1) according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Use `onblur` instead so anytime the input becomes unfocused the code runs to set it to the max

Comment: np, that seems like a great solution that does the same thing :D

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a watcher for this issue. I don't know if It is the best way but It works.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/cbertelegni/pen/RzXYOp?editors=1111)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-text-field
         v-model="number"
         type="number"
        min=0
         max=10>    
        </v-text-field>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      number: 0
    }
  },
  watch: {
    number (val, old) {
      console.log(val, old)
      if (+val > 10) {
        this.number = 10
      }
    }
   }
})
```

Comment: Any possible way to restrict the user from typing more than 2 or 3 digits?

Comment: @NandKishor Yes, every logic can be added in the same watcher.